# OneDrive Integration with MVC 4 application, Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, onedrive

I could not find an example of and MVC application integrated with OneDrive.
What I am interested in the most is how to handle authentication? What type works the best, if you take the two options described here https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm?
In my project I would like to manipulate user files from APp specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

They are working with an [issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/issues/45) to make this possible. OneDrive API does not have client secret support for the moment. But like @ginache says: "Authentication using client secret isn't fully implemented yet." You can use the SharePointClient, but it lacks access to shared files and folders.

If you find a workaround, please let me know.